# XCode 8 Comment out broken

Tags: xcode8, xcode8-beta6

On XCode 8 Beta 5 & 6 cannot use the comment out functionality. Seems it is disabled in the context menu and shortcut does not work.

I have submitted this to Apple via bugreport.apple.com and got a response that it has already been reported. I am on Mac OS 10.11.6

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From: https://twitter.com/kolpanic/status/763323546814844928

In Terminal: `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl`

Reboot.

Comment: Worked great. Well done, good find.

Comment: Thank you!! Worked. This was driving me nuts. Apple closed my bug report as a dupe.

Comment: Still actual for 8.1

Comment: sudo: /usr/libexec/xpccachect: command not found

Comment: Indeed actual for 8.1. Apple, hello ??

Comment: Doesn't work. Even since I updated from Xcode 7, along with my custom shortcuts, the simple comments shortcut doesn't work. Today updated to Xcode 8.2 (8C38) and still doesn't work. Running El Capitan.

Comment: I am sad that this is the actual answer, but it worked for me with Xcode 8.2

Comment: Just worked for me in 8.2.1. Why on earth is this still a bug?

Comment: This also works for Xcode 8.2 (8C38). Rebooting does not appear to be required. 

I cannot be certain, but the occurrence of this issue may be correlated with using Xcode to start and stop an app a large number of times in a relatively short period of time.

Comment: Command not found on High Sierra, any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue with the Xcode 8 GM version. I just moved Xcode 8 into another directory and opened it again. Then it works.

Comment: The terminal command no helps for me, but this is works! I simply quit the Xcode, rename Xcode's app name, and reopen it, then everything works fine. Awesome, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't, by some chance, commenting out the second line of a multi-line macro, are you?  If so, I already filed a bug about it, and it was broken in Xcode 7, too.

Otherwise, the way you fix it is to

- File a bug report at bugreport.apple.com
- Roll back to a previous version (or just ignore it and manually comment out the lines)

Comment: I am commenting uncommented lines (or at least trying). Seems it is problem with XCode. I will try raise a bug. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8 might not be fully supported by el captain, i couldn't make comment on el captain but now i can make comment when i updated my os to developer beta 7.

Answer (score 0):

XCode 8 GM is out for download which fixes issue: https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: I am using the full release of XCode 8, and this issue still persists. The accepted answer does solve the problem, but Apple hasn't fixed it.